# How to add embedded resource JSON file to ConfigurationBuilder without creating a temporary file?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have  `appsettings.json`  with build action set to `Embedded Resource`. I usually extract the file and make a new copy of it as follows.

```
string jsonFullPath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, "namespace.directory.appsettings.json");
Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

using (Stream resourceFileStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceFilename))
{
    if (resourceFileStream != null)
    {
        using (FileStream fileStream = File.Create(jsonFullPath))
        {
            resourceFileStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
        }
    }
}
```

And add the copy to an instance of `ConfigurationBuilder` as follows.

```
Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile(jsonFullPath, optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
    .Build();
```

## Question

Is it possible to make `ConfigurationBuilder` use the embedded JSON file directly without creating a new temporary file as I did above? If yes, how to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest that use [`AddJsonStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.jsonconfigurationextensions.addjsonstream?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#Microsoft_Extensions_Configuration_JsonConfigurationExtensions_AddJsonStream_Microsoft_Extensions_Configuration_IConfigurationBuilder_System_IO_Stream_) instead of `AddJsonfile`.

Useful resource [here](https://codemindinterface.com/2023/08/embedded-appsettings/) with sample code:

```
public static void AddEmbeddedJsonFile(this IConfigurationBuilder configuration, string resourceName)
{
    var host = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
    if (host == null)
        return;

    var fullFileName = $"{host.GetName().Name}.{resourceName}";
    using var input = host.GetManifestResourceStream(fullFileName);
    if (input != null)
    {
        configuration.AddJsonStream(input);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.NET Core 6, streaming the appsettings.ini from an embedded resource is done as follows:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(new WebApplicationOptions
{
    ContentRootPath = AppContext.BaseDirectory,//Path.GetFullPath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()),
    Args = args,
});

builder.Host.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
{    
    using (var resourceStream = this.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Namespace.filename.ext"))
    {
        config.AddJsonStream(resourceStream);
    }
}
...
```