# Is it possible to embedd the appsettings.json file?

Tags: c#

I want to share a simple app that uses an appsettings.json file internally. Just for cleaner code basically. But I only want to share a single exe.

Is it possible to use `IConfiguration` with the default `appsettings.json` file when it's setup as embedded resource?

Thanks

Comment: the appsettings contains data which you likely want to change *after* the app publication. Maybe you even have multiple deployment, each one with different settings.
So, how could you customize the deployment without any per-site file? however, if you prefer to avoid even a single file, just write your settings in the code, and that's all.

Comment: @MarioVernari is right. if it's necessary you can store the config in the C# file and get rid of the appsettings.json file. but that is not good practice

Comment: Isn't this an answer to the question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60249147/how-to-add-embedded-resource-json-file-to-configurationbuilder-without-creating